# Unable to find field with custom FieldBridge implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I can't seem to get the very basic `FieldBridge` implementation to work. It looks as if the indexing process is ignoring `@FieldBridge` annotation completely.

Here's the implementation:

```
public class LocalisedInformationBridge implements FieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {

        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(name + ".test", "test", document);

    }   
}
```

Entity with the `@FieldBridge` annotation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
@MapKey(name = "languageCode")
@IndexedEmbedded
@FieldBridge(impl = LocalisedInformationBridge.class)
private Map<String, LocalisedProductInformation> localisedProductInformation;
```

Contained entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="productId")
@ContainedIn
private Product product;
```

When I try to search on `localisedProductInformation.test` field, I'm getting exception:

> org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field
>   localisedProductInformation.test

Here's how I'm indexing data:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

The weird thing is when I put a breakpoint on `set` method of `LocalisedInformationBridge` class, debugger doesn't stop the execution of the program. Is there something very obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure is in the path and being loaded? Do something silly like a default constructor that prints a message. This way you'd know that is being loaded at least

Comment: The log says that all entities have been reindexed and when I print a message from constructor, I can see it for all entities...

Comment: How does the container know that your implementation is for that index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to know is, when you use @IndexedEmbedded on a container property (array, collection or map), any field bridge defined in a @Field annotation will be applied to elements of this property's value.
So in your case, the field bridge will be applied to the map's values, not to the map itself. If your map is empty, the field bridge won't be applied at all. Is this your case?

This behavior is admittedly a bit strange (given that `@IndexedEmbedded` has a slightly different purpose), but it's been introduced a while ago and fixing it would lead to regressions for users relying on it. So, until a new major version is released, this is likely to stay that way...

Comment: Yes, that was the case and when I removed the IndexedEmbedded annotations, this started to work properly. I'm just wondering if IndexedEmbedded annotation is needed for ContainedIn annotation to work on the other side of relationship, or could that be used on its own?

Comment: @fuudge The `@IndexedEmbedded` annotation isn't required for the `@ContainedIn` annotation to work. You should be alright without it, assuming you use your own field bridge.